# Why does my Boost Library fail to link?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I'm using a MacBook Pro, running MacOS 10.13.1; installed boost via homebrew using the following:

```
brew install boost --build-from-source
```

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace boostfs = boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1) 
{
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

boostfs::path p(argv[1]);

if (boostfs::exists(p))
{
    std::cout << "File " << p << " exists." << std::endl;
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "File " << p << " does not exist." << std::endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am receiving is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
  boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&) in chkfile-c30777.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in chkfile-c30777.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in chkfile-c30777.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in chkfile-c30777.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [chkfile] Error 1
```

I ran the code in the terminal using `make` and `gcc 7.2.0`.

I attempted the following:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I /usr/local/include/ chkfile.cpp -o chkfile
```

and got a new error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)", referenced from:
boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::path const&) in cce7HDO8.o
"boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in cce7HDO8.o
"boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::error_condition const&) const in cce7HDO8.o 

boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::error_code const&, int) const in cce7HDO8.o
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in cce7HDO8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Please copy and paste the exact text into the question.

Comment: What commands specifically did you use to build and link the code?  Do you just type `make` at the prompt and hope for the best?  Most Makefiles default to echoing the compile and link commands they are running--what does the output in the console say?

Comment: I just added the error. Also, I'm simply running `make` from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include filesystem this way

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
```

Make sure you linked proper libraries

```
-lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```